# how can reorder column in DataTable in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

Importing data from Excel to VisualBasic, I am using the following code to reorder the columns:

```
  Dim new_postion As Integer = dt_Excel.Columns.Count - 1
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt_Excel.Columns.Count - 1
                dt_Excel.Columns(i).SetOrdinal(new_postion)
                new_postion = new_postion - 1
            Next
            DGV_Excel.DataSource = dt_Excel
```

but when I show the data in DataGridView it's still in the same order.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying will not work after assigning the DataTable to the DataGridView, at least not in a proper way.

Set the positions prior to assigning the DataTable to the DataGridView.DataSource would be best but if not possible then use DisplayIndex e.g. `DataGridView1.Columns(x).DisplayIndex = y`

Where x is the column index to change and y is what we will change too.

If by chance you created DataGridView columns in the IDE then DisplayIndex is the only way to go.

Comment: i don't want to order it in DataGridView only, i need to order the DataTable because i wont to Compared with the another DataTable i wont  to make it  easy to compare

Comment: Hi Steve, I would had replied with a different suggestion if you had indicated the new requirement (as it was not in the initial question) but even then doing compares the ordinal position does not matter as you can use (not knowing exactly how you are comparing so this may not work thus more details the better). this is conceptual to get the point across Dim result As Boolean = If(dt1.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("FirstName") = dt2.Rows(0).Field(Of String)("FirstName"), True, False)

Comment: i'm sorry but you didn't understand me because my English is not good , look what i want to do i have database SQL server in the database i have table i bought data to vb in DataTable1 and show it in DataGridView1 then i import excel sheet to vb in DataTable2 and show it in DataGridView2 to add the data in SQL table but before i add it i wont to  compare it with  DataTable1  but  DataTable2 is not the same column order with DataTable1 i wont to reorder DataTable2 ( i know i can  compare it without reorder it but i wont to make it easy to my team )

Comment: i just wont how can i reorder datatable and i'm sorry again

Comment: Please explain how you are attempting to reorder currently and would also suggest editing your initial question to show what you have tried so far in regards to the re-ordering/compare.

Comment: see the pitcher in my answer comment

Answer (score 1):

Okay, let's go back to SetOrdinal, here I am loading data from a database, note the ID column position in the SELECT statement then in the DataSet Visualizer.
[image]

No different then using Excel
[image]

Comment: it's working when i write like this but when i put it inside loop it's doesn't work i don't know why

Comment: Why it does not work for you is a mystery especially without seeing your updated code.

Comment: i solved it it's the same code just i changed dt_Excel.Columns(i).SetOrdinal(new_postion) to dt_Excel.Columns(0).SetOrdinal(new_postion) now its work thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

[image: cODE IN IMAGE FORMAT]
 look that's my code i want to order right to left 
[image: Output of the image]

i wont order green one like over it

Answer (score 0):

Mocked example ordering right to left as per your comment

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim dt1 As New DataTable
        dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "FirstName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "MiddleName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt1.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "LastName", .DataType = GetType(String)})

        dt1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Karen", "", "Payne"})
        dt1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Kevin", "S", "Gallagher"})
        dt1.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Mary", "D", "Jones"})


        Dim dt2 As New DataTable
        dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "LastName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "FirstName", .DataType = GetType(String)})
        dt2.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "MiddleName", .DataType = GetType(String)})

        dt2.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Payne", "Karen", ""})
        dt2.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Gallagher", "Kevin", "S"})
        dt2.Rows.Add(New Object() {"Jones", "Mary", "D"})


        Dim reverseList = dt1.Columns _
            .Cast(Of DataColumn) _
            .Select(
                Function(column, index)
                    Return New With {.Position = index, .Name = column.ColumnName}
                End Function) _
            .OrderByDescending(Function(item) item.Position) _
            .ToList

        For Each item In reverseList
            If dt2.Columns.Contains(item.Name) Then
                dt2.Columns(item.Name).SetOrdinal(item.Position)
            End If
        Next
    End Sub
End Module
```